# Free times based on duration - NODEJS

Tags: node.js, duration, timeslots

I have a list with busy times. With my code below I have managed to find the free time slots available within the busy times. However I want to find the free time slots based on a duration given. The code below generates my available gaps but I want to generate them based on duration. For example if the duration is 30 minutes, it should generate available times that can be 30 minutes.

```
var free_slots = []; 
var start_time = '08:00:00';
var end_time = '17:00:00';
busy_slots.sort(function(a, b){
    return new Date(a.Time_Start) > new Date(b.Time_Start)? 1: -1;
  });
 for(var i=0, l=busy_slots.length; i<l; i++){
    if(prettyDate2(new Date(busy_slots[i].Time_Start)) < start_time){
        busy_slots.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }

}
for(var i=0, l=busy_slots.length; i<l; i++){
    end_time = busy_slots[i].Time_Start;
    if(i)
    start_time = busy_slots[i-1].Time_End;

    if((end_time && !i) || (end_time && i && busy_slots[i-1].Time_End < busy_slots[i].Time_Start) )
    free_slots.push({date: getDate(busy_slots[i].Time_End) ,start_time: start_time, end_time: end_time});

    if(i+1 === l){
        start_time = busy_slots[i].Time_End;

        if(start_time)
        free_slots.push({ date: getDate(busy_slots[i].Time_End), start_time: start_time, end_time: '17:00:00'});
      }

}
 return free_slots;
```

Comment: If you already can manage available slots, with the start time and the end time, you just need to subtract them and get the duration to compare with what is required.

Comment: As in, calculate the time diff between the start and end and then compare to the duration? var diff = start_time - end_time and then compare the diff to the duration?